# Python Changing Textual Values to Numerical Values Output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I currently have a data set with a bunch of different columns listed below stating "No" or "Yes", "Female" or "Male". I wanted to change the No's and Females to 0 and Yes and Males to 1. I included the picture of what I'm trying to do below.
[image]
The code doesnt error out but the output I'm getting is below. Please help!
[image]
Null = dF.isnull() .any()

```
dF = dF.drop(["customerID", "gender", "SeniorCitizen", "Partner", "Dependents", "tenure", "PhoneService", "MultipleLines", "InternetService", "OnlineSecurity", "OnlineBackup", "DeviceProtection", "TechSupport", "StreamingTV", "StreamingMovies", "Contract", "PaperlessBilling", "PaymentMethod", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges", "Churn"], axis=1)

for column in range(len(list(dF.columns.values))):
    for index, row in dF.iterrows():
         if "No" in row[column] or "Female" in row[column]:
            dF.iloc[index, column] = 0
    
         elif "Yes" in row[column] or "Male" in row[column]:
            dF.iloc[index, column] = 1
        
dF.to_excel('Cleaned.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Google ‘One-hot encoding’. It is the process of transforming categorical values to numerical. There is a native pandas function for it:  `get_dummies()`. See: https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-and-how-to-use-pandas-get-dummies-function-922eb9bd4970

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple conditions that you want to modify your variables to, you can use the `np.select()` function to specify the choices and the outputs for those choices. This is similar to how the `case_when()` function works in R's dplyr package.

```py
for col_name in df.columns:
    df[col_name] = np.select([df[col_name] == x for x in ['No','Female','Yes','Male']],
                                                         [0   , 0      , 1   , 1    ])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html